# Node.js app works locally but when deploy to heroku I get application error

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, web-scraping

I built a web scraper for live sports scores. I have 2 files an index.js which acts as the server and a scraper.js file that does the scraping. This is my code for the index.js file :

```
const express = require('express');

const scraper = require('./util/scraper');

const app = express();

app.get('/scores', (req, res) => {
    const scores = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        scraper
         .scrapeLiveScores()
         .then(data => {
             resolve(data)
        }).catch(err => reject('scores scrape failed'))
    });

    // res.send(JSON.stringify(scores));
    // Use promise.all([]) if more than one scraper is used and list each of them
    Promise.resolve(scores)
     .then(data => {
         res.send(JSON.stringify(data));
     }).catch(function() {
         console.log("promise rejected");
     });
});

app.set( 'port', ( process.env.PORT || 5000 ));

// Start node server
app.listen( app.get( 'port' ), function() {
  console.log( 'Node server is running on port ' + app.get( 'port' ));
  });
module.exports = app;
```

When I run heroku local it returns a json of the data I need. But when I deployed it to heroku I get an application error with a console log of "promise rejected".

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');


const scrapeLiveScores = async () => {
    try{
        //Open the browser
        var browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: true });

        //Open a new page
        var page = await browser.newPage();

        //Enter url in the page
        await page.goto('https://www.flashscore.com.au/basketball/usa/nba/');

        //wait for selector to load in
        await page.waitForSelector('div.event__score.event__score--home');

        var scores = await page.evaluate(() => {
            var basePath = 'div.leagues--live > div > div.event__match';
            var homeScore = document.querySelectorAll('div.leagues--live > div > div.event__match > div.event__score--home');
            var awayScore = document.querySelectorAll('div.leagues--live > div > div.event__match > div.event__score--away');
            var homeTeam = document.querySelectorAll('div.leagues--live > div > div.event__match > div.event__participant.event__participant--home');
            var awayTeam = document.querySelectorAll('div.leagues--live > div > div.event__match > div.event__participant.event__participant--away');
            var stages = document.querySelectorAll('div.leagues--live > div > div.event__match > div.event__stage > div');


            //#g_3_6LLArB7N > div.event__stage > div
            var scoresArray = [];

            for(var i = 0; i < homeScore.length; i++){

                if(stages[i] != null){
                    scoresArray[i] = {
                        homeTeam: homeTeam[i].innerText.trim(),
                        homeScore: homeScore[i].innerText.trim(),
                        awayTeam: awayTeam[i].innerText.trim(),
                        awayScore: awayScore[i].innerText.trim(),
                        stage: stages[i].innerText.trim()
                    };
                }else{
                    scoresArray[i] = {
                        homeTeam: homeTeam[i].innerText.trim(),
                        homeScore: homeScore[i].innerText.trim(),
                        awayTeam: awayTeam[i].innerText.trim(),
                        awayScore: awayScore[i].innerText.trim(),
                        stage: "-"
                    };
                }

            }

            return scoresArray;
        });

        console.log(scores);
        await browser.close();
        return scores;
    }catch(err){

        await browser.close();
    }
}

module.exports.scrapeLiveScores = scrapeLiveScores;
```

Ive been stuck on this for hours. Here is the log:

```
2019-12-30T08:06:23.178178+00:00 app[web.1]: scraper error TypeError: Cannot read property 'close' of undefined
2019-12-30T08:06:23.178216+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.scrapeLiveScores (/app/util/scraper.js:60:23)
2019-12-30T08:06:23.178218+00:00 app[web.1]:     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
2019-12-30T08:06:23.182971+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/scores" host=nbalive-api.herokuapp.com request_id=7f5b79cc-dd2e-433b-a4db-56052f8a5cdd fwd="99.247.208.27" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=23ms status=500 bytes=231 protocol=https
```

Line 60 is the in the catch(err){await browswer.close()}

Comment: Did you add the webpacks for puppeteer and nodejs?

Answer (score 0):

To debug this problem, you need to log the actual error you're getting. And, while you're at it, simplify the code and remove the promise anti-pattern of wrapping an existing promise in another unnecessary promise.

Change the code to this:

```
app.get('/scores', (req, res) => {
    scraper.scrapeLiveScores().then(data => {
         res.send(data);
    }).catch(function(e) {
         console.log("scraper error", e);
         res.status(500).send("scraper error");
     });
});
```

Then that `console.log()` statement in the `.catch()` will show you the exact error you're getting.

Besides removing the promise anti-pattern, simplifying the code and logging the actual error you get and eliminating the `JSON.stringify()` which is done automatically by `res.send()`, this also sends a response to the request when there's an error rather than just leaving the browser hanging.

Comment: thanks for the help. I tried your solution and it works locally but on the deployed heroku app I now get a "scraper error" I'll add the code for the scraper.js file to my question

Comment: @hhhenry54 - The debugging point of what I show here is not the "scraper error" part it's the `e` in the `console.log("scraper error", e)`.  That SHOULD be showing you what the scraper error is so you can perhaps figure out what's going on.  ALWAYS log errors like this so you can troubleshoot why it's happening.

Comment: @hhhenry54 - My guess is that the error occurs in the `catch` block where you do `await browser.close()`.  Again, log the ACTUAL error in the `catch()` and you will get a better idea what the original error was.  Don't ever hide the real error.  Always log it.

Comment: @hhhenry54 - For example if `await puppeteer.launch({ headless: true });` rejects, then `browser` will not have a value, but you will try to call `browser.close()` in the `catch` block.

Comment: @hhhenry54 - I'd suggest changing `browser.close()` in your `catch` to `if (browser) {browser.close();}  throw err;`.  You need to test `browser` before using it and you need to propagate your error back to the caller by rethrowing.  Even cleaner to do just one `if (browser) {browser.close();}` in a `finally` block, not a `catch`.  Then, you don't need to duplicate it.

Answer (score 0):

I've not used scraper but I have successfully used Cheerio and Puppeteer on Heroku:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

const $ = require('cheerio');

exports.scraper = (req, res) => {
  const url = 'https://www.my-target-url.com';
  puppeteer
    .launch()
    .then(function(browser) {
      return browser.newPage();
    })
    .then(function(page) {
      return page.goto(url).then(function() {
        return page.content();
      });
    })
    .then(function(html) {
      // target a css selector
      $('#my_selector', html).each(function() {

        console.log($(this).text());
        res.send($(this).text());
      });
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      //handle error
    });
};
```